# Add property to non user defined classes

Tags: c#, inheritance, dynamic, polymorphism

We use controls all the time for example a button and sometimes we may want to add some custom properties to that button. For example numberOfTimesClicked etc. I am currently working with GridViewColumnHeader  and I would like to add the property columnIndex to that class. I know I can keep track of the columns with other methods but I am just curios to know if we can add extra properties to classes. For example I was thinking about inheritance. If I create a new class and inherit from the class that I want to add new properties (in my case GridViewColumnHeader)  then I think that should work but for some reason I get errors in my code whenever I do something like:

```
private class MyGridViewColumnHeader : GridViewColumnHeader
{
    public int propertyThatIWantToAdd { get; set; }
}
```

from now on if I instantiate objects from MyGridViewColumnHeader class  instead of GridViewColumnHeader class I get errors. What is wrong with using inheritance to achieve this?

Comment: what kind of errors do you get?

Comment: we can't help if you don't say what your error is...

Comment: I have an event that gets fired when user clicks on header column. If I cast the sender object to GridViewColumnHeader I get no errors but if I cast it to MyGridViewColumnHeader I get the following error:   Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumnHeader' to type 'MyGridViewColumnHeader'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of casting the `sender` object use

```
e.OriginalSource as MyGridViewColumnHeader
```

And do your work on that object. If you need to know what is inside the `RoutedEventArgs` have a look on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs.aspx)

Comment: Exactly, know I understand why I was only getting some errors. I can cast from someClass to MysomeClass but I cannot cast from MySomeClass to someClass. I modified the delegates and instead of passing a someClass parameter I told it to pass a MySomeClass paramter and now everything works great!

Comment: so e.OriginalSource turn out to be someClass and I could not cast someClass to MySomeClass. It is the other way arrount you are right when you said I had to see what paramter was being passed

Answer (score 0):

You should make the class `public`, the `private` modifier is only allowed for inner classes.

Also you should use [Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750428.aspx) instead of normal Properties, if you want to access the property in XAML.

Comment: I still get an error. I don't understand why I cannot cast cast GridViewColumnHeader to MyGridViewColumnHeader if MyGridViewColumnHeader inherits from GridViewColumnHeader. One of the errors that I get is:     Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumnHeader' to type 'MyGridViewColumnHeader'.

Comment: @Tom: Give us your real, unadultered, raw exception so we know what error you are having... Or forever hold your peace (piece?)..